# Visual Studio IDE Customisation - Breakpoint string highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide, customization

I'm trying to make my IDE fonts and colours more visible, but I'm stuck on one last detail: the string highlighting for selected breakpoints.

Given the following example:

```
Session["mySessionVar"] = someValue;
```

The text for "mySessionVar" - including the quote marks - has (in my case) yellow text on a bright pink background - almost impossible to read.  My problem is I can't find any way to set the Breakpoint (Enabled) strings, keys or parameters to a more readable setting.

Can it even be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you've tried changing the various "Breakpoint" settings in `Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors`, but even those wouldn't leave the string a different color than any other text in the breakpoint.  The intent, for breakpoints, is that the foreground color of everything in the breakpoint is overridden by the breakpoint foreground color.

Do you have an extension installed that changes the formatting for comments, or did you get into this state just from changing around options in Fonts and Colors?

Comment: The latter.  Thanks for framing the issue around the "intent" of the setting.  Makes a bit more sense I suppose.  I'll fiddle it around to take that into account.

Comment: If it still gives you issues, though, please file a Connect bug with how you got into this state.  That's useful feedback as we think about new versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: oh well, I'd like the 'automatic' colour to not override existing behaviour. For example, while I can change the breakpoint text and background to a single colour, I can't say 'leave it alone' and use the standard syntax-highlighted colouring used by the default text colour options. I hate the background highlighting of breakpoints, makes me think I'm working in VB6!